# letsencrypt-auto certonly does'nt work

Tags: centos, lets-encrypt

no matter which command I use with ./letsencypt-auto the result is always the same as blew, am I missing something here.
here is an output on ./letsencrypt-auto certonly.

```
[root@tipsycore letsencrypt]# ./letsencrypt-auto certonly
#Bootstrapping dependencies for RedHat-based OSes...
#yum is /usr/bin/yum
#Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
#Setting up Install Process
#Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
# * base: mirror.zetup.net
# * epel: ftp.lysator.liu.se
# * extras: mirror.zetup.net
# * updates: mirror.zetup.net
#Package python-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
#Package python-devel-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest #version
#Package python-virtualenv-1.10.1-1.el6.noarch already installed and latest #version
#Nothing to do
#Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
#Setting up Install Process
#Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
# * base: mirror.zetup.net
# * epel: ftp.lysator.liu.se
# * extras: mirror.zetup.net
# * updates: mirror.zetup.net
#Package gcc-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
#Package dialog-1.1-9.20080819.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest #version
#Package augeas-libs-1.0.0-10.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
#Package openssl-devel-1.0.1e-42.el6_7.2.x86_64 already installed and latest #version
#Package libffi-devel-3.0.5-3.2.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest #version
#Package redhat-rpm-config-9.0.3-44.el6.centos.noarch already installed and #latest version
#Package ca-certificates-2015.2.4-65.0.1.el6_6.noarch already installed and #latest version
#Nothing to do
#Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
#Setting up Install Process
#Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
# * base: mirror.zetup.net
# * epel: ftp.lysator.liu.se
# * extras: mirror.zetup.net
# * updates: mirror.zetup.net
#Package 2:mod_ssl-2.2.15-47.el6.vm.x86_64 already installed and latest #version
#Nothing to do
#WARNING: Python 2.6 support is very experimental at present...
#if you would like to work on improving it, please ensure you have backups
#and then run this script again with the --debug flag!
#[root@tipsycore letsencrypt]#
```

Comment: Anything which regards Python 2.6 as "experimental" is probably going to give you trouble. Version 2.7 was released in 2010, and [Python 2 EoL has been declared for 2020](https://pythonclock.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

### Lets encrypt Centos 6

```
# yum install centos-release-SCL
# yum install python27 python27-python-devel python27-python-setuptools python27-python-tools python27-python-virtualenv
# ln -s /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
# ln -s /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so
# ll /usr/lib64/libpyt*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      19 Aug 22  2016 /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so -> libpython2.6.so.1.0
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 root root 1669840 Aug 18  2016 /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      51 Mar  1 17:59 /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so -> /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      51 Mar  1 17:59 /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 -> /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
# /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.8
# vim ~/.bash_profile
PATH=/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/:$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
# python -V
Python 2.6.6
# source  ~/.bash_profile
# python -V
Python 2.7.8
# git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt
# cd /opt/letsencrypt/
# service nginx stop
# ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d <YOUR_DOMAIN.COM>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (somewhat confusingly) described by the last message you get in the output from letsencrypt-auto:

```
#WARNING: Python 2.6 support is very experimental at present...
#if you would like to work on improving it, please ensure you have backups
#and then run this script again with the --debug flag!
```

The LetsEncrypt client you are running requires Python 2.7 or above.  You have Python 2.6 installed. I have a blog post describing the way I solved this problem:  https://thelastcicada.com/solving-the-python-2-6-issue-for-letencrypt-on-centos-6.  Below I will go into further detail and summarize my solution.

I'm going to assume from this issue and the output of your letsencrypt-auto that you are running CentOS 6 or a similar RHEL6-based operating system.  This is important because systems tools on CentOS 6 are all based on Python 2.6 (yum in particular is) and your system can therefore not upgrade safely past Python 2.6.  CentOS 7 doesn't have this problem and comes packaged with a newer version of Python.

To solve this on CentOS 6, you could run `letsencrypt-auto --debug`, as noted in the error message, but that just allows you to run the experimental Python 2.6 code that isn't yet well supported.  Alternatively, you can use Software Collections to install Python 2.7 on CentOS 6 in it's own environment that can run alongside Python 2.6 and not mess up your system's default Python installation.

The basic steps are:

1. `yum install centos-release-SCL` to install the Software Collections package
2. `yum install python27` to install Python 2.7
3. `scl enable python27 "/root/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto certonly  --agree-tos --webroot --webroot-path /var/www/html/mywebsite.com -d mywebsite.com"` to run the LetsEncrypt client using the Python 2.7 version via Software Collections.  The flags passed to letsencrypt-auto are typical ones I use when requesting an SSL certificate to install with Nginx - your configuration my vary.

Hope this helps and good luck!